# How to start counter when a specific div come into view

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollview

I have a plugins.init.js file in which this try catch is running on page load. I want this to run when the counter-value div come into view. Is there a way to run it only one time when the div come into view

```
try {
  const counter = document.querySelectorAll(".counter-value");
  const speed = 2500; // The lower the slower

  counter.forEach((counter_value) => {
    const updateCount = () => {
      const target = +counter_value.getAttribute("data-target");
      const count = +counter_value.innerText;

      // Lower inc to slow and higher to slow
      var inc = target / speed;

      if (inc < 1) {
        inc = 1;
      }

      // Check if target is reached
      if (count < target) {
        // Add inc to count and output in counter_value
        counter_value.innerText = (count + inc).toFixed(0);
        // Call function every ms
        setTimeout(updateCount, 1);
      } else {
        counter_value.innerText = target;
      }
    };

    updateCount();
  });
} catch (err) {}
```

Comment: You could use the Intersection Observer API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API.

Comment: An easy to use library for that is scrollama: https://github.com/russellgoldenberg/scrollama.

Comment: You can use document.activeElement

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the Intersection Observer API that is part of the browser.

The observer will wait for the specified element to come into view and then execute som callback when that happens.

You can read about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API).

Good luck!